# Module 'path_provider_foundation' not found

Tags: flutter, xcode

I'm new to flutter and xcode. I bought a small project and tried running it after making suring the dependencies are good but I got a error stating Module 'path_provider_foundation' not found. Can I please get some help with this issue.

I tried opening runner.xcworkspace instead of runner.xcodeproj. I tried flutter clean. I tried a few others stuff with the limited souces I got from google but nothing help.

Comment: Did you try `flutter pub get`? This step will install dependencies listed in `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi @jraufeisen, yes I did however, this didn't fix the issue. I also tried updating ruby and reinstalled cocoapods but that still didn't fix the issue.